# How can I populate the value of a list<string> from base class to child class?

Tags: c#

I have a model M1 which has a List as below:

```
class M1 {

[NotMapped] List<string> list1 {get; set;}

}
```

I have another model M2 which has a List as below:

```
class M2 { 

List<string> list2 {get; set;}
}
```

How can I get the value of list1 from M1 class into list2 in M2 class ? Thanks.

Comment: `<M2 instance>.list2 = <M1 instance>.list1;` Have you tried this? And in your title you mention from base class to child class, which class is base and child? Assume that M1 is base/parent class and M2 is child. M2 should inherit M1 and you don't need the `list2` property: `public class M2 : M1 {  } ` as M2 will inherit all the behaviors (properties, method) from M1.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem here. You've simply asked how to get and set a property. If you don't know that already then you need to stop what you're doing and work through a beginners tutorial. If you do know that  then just do it. If the actual problem is something else, you need to do a better job of explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate list2 in your M2 class, create a method (or use a constructor) in M2 that takes an instance of M1. Then set list1 from M1 to List2 in M2.